# CefSharp загрузка вебсайта из ресурсов приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, cefsharp

Здравствуйте, знатоки! 
Помогите решить задачу:  Имеем html сайт, который загружен в корень проекта.
Все файлы имеют свойство встроенного контента.
Как я могу загрузить свой сайт  из самого  приложения?
Этот вариант не дал результатов

```
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser
        x:Name="browser"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Address="/web/index.html" />
```

Работает только такой вариант

```
string dir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        String page = string.Format("{0}\\web\\index.html", dir);
        browser.Address = page;
```

Но, при условии, если вебсайт находится рядом с exe файлом

Comment: Попробуйте использовать в качестве `Uri` путь, `new  Uri("pack://application:,,,/web/index.html", UriKind.Relative);`

Comment: Или же `siteoforigin` new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,;component/web/index.html", UriKind.Relative);

Comment: ругается на абсолютный путь

Comment: Попробуйте не указывать UriKind, и загляните сюда [URI типа "pack" в WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Не удается преобразовать в строку, но если поставить ToString() - отображает пустую страницу Uri myUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/web/index.html");
 browser.Address = myUri;

Comment: Тогда вам придется выгружать данные из приложения, и загружать их оттуда. Копайте в сторону "выгрузка ресурсов прилодения"

Comment: Попробую, спасибо